# Does anyone knows how Microsoft default WPF controls are loaded into Visual Studio's Toolbox?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, user-controls, controls

When the WPF window is opened in design view in Visual Studio, the Toolbox pane automatically loads WPF controls into "Common WPF Controls" tab and "All WPF Controls" tab.

Does anyone know how Visual Studio does this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like they would be loaded through either the Project References or the (more likely) user options saved when you rightclick on the tookbox and choose "Choose Items...".

I would imagine that somewhere, there is a setting where by default when a XAML page is open, it loads a bunch of items in System.Windows.Controls into the Toolbox.  If you want, you can deselect those items you dont want, and put different items in the toolbox

Comment: Did this answer your question or have I gotten off track?

Comment: What I wanted to know is, how does the VisualStudio loads the controls into "Common WPF Controls" and "All WPF Controls" tabs.

If it were WinForms application, I can use VisualStudioSDK and write some code to add WinFormControls that I want to a tab. But for some reason I cannot do that for WPF controls. So I was wondering How Microsoft loads their controls into the VStoolbox?
The "choose items" options is when the user needs to do some mouse clicks. I dont want that,what I want is a programmatic way of loading WPF controls into the toolbox! and hide those which i dont want in the toolbox!

Comment: I am afraid I have no idea about that, sorry.